# Maven nexus-staging-maven-plugin doesn't deploy correctly

Tags: java, maven, deployment, nexus

I'm trying to deploy using maven deploy pluging but deploy doesn't use the correct name for the artifact

[INFO] Installing C:\Users\user\git\artifact\artifact\target\myArtifact-0.0.10.15-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\user.m2\repository\com\my\pc\new\version\artifactId-0.0.10.jar

The compilation phase generate the artifact without problems but the install doesn't take the correct name and also use another groupid.

It's the same problem with the upload, but it doesn't finish because the name doesn't finish with snapshot.

My configuration it's

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <file>${project.name}-${project.version}.${buildNumber}-SNAPSHOT.jar</file>
                <version>${project.version}.${buildNumber}</version>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                <repositoryId>snapshot</repositoryId>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshot/</url>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: The triplet `${groupId}:${artifactId}:${version}` (plus the packaging type and an optional qualifier) is what identifies your artifact. The Maven Install Plugin uses that to compose the installed artifact name and path and will **not** let you use any other convention. If `${buildNumber}` and `-SNAPSHOT` are supposed to be part of the final artifact version, put them inside the `<version>` tag. No other configuration will work with Maven

Comment: I'd changed the artifactId and now it's take the correct name in install but ignores the ${buildnumber}-SNAPSHOT